# Debugging ScalaTest in VSCode, how can I specify matching string (-z argument)

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, scalatest

I'm using VSCode for Scala development and am using the ScalaTest framework for writing tests. I'd like to only run tests within a Spec that match a string, usually done with the -z argument to ScalaTest. This is what I have tried in my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "scala",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "MyFirstDebugRun",
            "testClass": "foo.bar.MyScalaTestSpec",
            "args": ["-z", "8.b"],
        }

    ]
}
```

This does work to run all the tests in `MyScalaTestSpec` (and no other Specs in my project), but in my normal flow it would only run those that match the string "8.b". How can I get it to only run that specific test case?

The Spec is roughly:

```
package foo.bar

import org.scalatest.funspec.AnyFunSpec

class MyScalaTestSpec extends AnyFunSpec {

  describe("This test shows that") {
    it("8.b: This case works ") {
    }
  }
}
```